# Is it safe to delete unnecessary wordpress user metadata?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm having performance issues with my Wordpress site, due to the number of registered users, the `wp_usermeta` table has almost 70 million rows.

Users do not have access to modify their profile so I have thought about deleting the unnecessary metadata that Wordpress creates when registering a new user. The following rows are created for a normal user:

```
+----------------------+------------------------------+
| meta_key             | meta_value                   |
+----------------------+------------------------------+
| nickname             | [USER_NICKNAME]              |
| first_name           |                              |
| last_name            |                              |
| description          |                              |
| rich_editing         | true                         |
| syntax_highlighting  | true                         |
| comment_shortcuts    | false                        |
| admin_color          | fresh                        |
| use_ssl              | 0                            |
| show_admin_bar_front | true                         |
| locale               |                              |
| wpe_capabilities     | a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;} |
| wpe_user_level       | 0                            |
| default_password_nag |                              |
| session_tokens       | [SESSION_DATA]               |
+----------------------+------------------------------+
```

I have thought of deleting all rows except `nickname` and `session_tokens`. Will i have a problem if i do this? Is there a way for Wordpress to not create these rows for new users?

Comment: You will probably get more expert answers at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BillKarwin I already asked there but I had no luck

Comment: You asked one day ago. Understand that it may take more time on the less popular stackexchange sites to get an answer. Stack Overflow gets more traffic, but it has a specific goal to solve code problems, not usage of individual software products. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for clarification.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, did you end up deleting those metadata ? We are having the same problem with 20 millions rows in this table. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe.

Check this solution

This has been explained here in full.

[Remove Unnecessary WP Postmeta](https://codepangs.com/delete-unnecessary-post-metadata/)

All you have to do is add the following in your theme functions.php file

```html
function delete_useless_post_meta() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug')); }
add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to improve the indexing of `usermeta` as described in

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

(That discusses `postmeta` adjust as needed to modify `usermeta`.)